# C stack using array

Tags: c, singly-linked-list

This is only a part of the program but I don't understand these codes why did we declare int* array in structure what does it mean?
Also we generally use int or void before function type why did we write struct Stack * before create function and also what is the use of unsigned here? Click the link to view the actual program. 
[a link](http://geeksquiz.com/stack-set-1/)

```
struct Stack {
    int top;
    unsigned capacity;
    int* array;
};

struct Stack* createStack(unsigned capacity) {
    struct Stack* stack = (struct Stack*) malloc(sizeof(struct Stack));
    stack->capacity = capacity;
    stack->top = -1;
    stack->array = (int*) malloc(stack->capacity * sizeof(int));
    return stack;
}

int main() {
    struct Stack* stack = createStack(100);
}
```

Comment: Don't be offended, but you need to have a basic course on `c` data types. There are lot of basic conceptual problems.

Comment: `int *` is not an array, it's a pointer.

Comment: Unsigned means unsigned int.

Comment: @iharob In a linked list we use a next pointer to point to the next ele but as array is contagious so we do not need a pointer so why use a pointer here?

Comment: @SouravGhosh can u suggest some courses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) int * is used because we dont know before hand how huge the array is going to be, so we declare it as a pointer and do malloc using the capacity of the stack.

If we had used an array, we had to perform additonal checks to see if our initial declared size was overflown and would be a huge overhead across the program.

2) The function create stack is returning the structure ponter of type stack, according to the syntax for functions.

Syntas:

```
<return type> function_name(<Parameters>){<Statements>}
```

3) We want the program to give us an error if some one tries to declare a negative capacity. Unsigned ensures that that is satisfied

Hope this helps.

Comment: So, basically the create stack is used to create a structure big enough to hold 100 array elements..
In linked list we create seperate nodes i.e, seperate structures but of same type for holding more than 1 elements but here are we creating only one structure or seperate structure of the same type for 100 elements each?

Comment: 1 structure. 100 int elements allocated. but in yoru link only 3 are used.

Comment: what do you mean only 3 are used we have created a stack of 100 elements [create stack(100)]

Comment: see the example in your link. He is creating a stack that can hold 100 integers, but for demo, he is pushing 10, 20, 30 (using 3 integer spaces). Then popping 30 (removing one from stack). then displaying top of stack (after removing 30 TOS is 20)

Answer (score 1):

> why did we declare int* array in structure what does it mean?

The `array` member is used to store the contents of the stack.  However, we don't know ahead of time how many elements the stack will need to hold, so we can't declare it as a regular array (whose size must be known at compile time<sup>1</sup>).  Instead, we'll allocate the memory at runtime using the `malloc` library function, which returns a pointer to the first element of the dynamically allocated block; this pointer will be stored to the array member.

> why did we write struct Stack * before create function

Because the `createStack` function is returning a pointer to a new `struct Stack` instance:

```
struct Stack *createStack( ... )  ----------------+
{                                                 | The type of the expression in the 
  struct Stack *stack = ...; -----+               | `return` statement must match the  
  ...                             |               | return type of the function
  return stack; <-----------------+---------------+
}
```

> what is the use of unsigned here

`unsigned` is short for `unsigned int`; it guarantees that only non-negative values can be used for the stack size.

Here's what memory looks like after the `createStack` function has been called:

```
                   +---+
            stack: |   |----+  // The stack variable points to a struct Stack instance
                   +---+    |
                    ...     |
                   +---+    |
       stack->top: |   |<---+  // The actual struct Stack instance is created on the heap
                   +---+       // The -> operator allows us to refer to the members of the
  stack->capacity: |   |       // instance through the stack pointer variable.
                   +---+       
     stack->array: |   |----+  // The memory for the stack contents is allocated in a 
                   +---+    |  // separate malloc call, and the resulting pointer is
                    ...     |  // stored in the instance's array member.  
                   +---+    |
  stack->array[0]: |   |<---+
                   +---+
  stack->array[1]: |   |
                   +---+
  stack->array[2]: |   |
                   +---+
                    ...
                   +---+
stack->array[N-1]: |   |    // N == stack->capacity
                   +---+
```

The `stack` variable in `main` points to an instance of `struct Stack`; this instance is created by the line

```
struct Stack* stack = (struct Stack*) malloc(sizeof(struct Stack));
```

in the `createStack` function.  The memory for the stack instance is taken from the "heap" (a region of memory reserved for dynamic allocation).  Within the stack instance, the `array` member also points to a region of dynamic memory reserved by another call to `malloc`:

```
stack->array = (int*) malloc(stack->capacity * sizeof(int));
```

This function sets aside enough memory to store as many `int` objects as specified in the `capacity` member.

**Edit**

Note that both `malloc` calls can be cleaned up as follows:

```
struct Stack *stack = malloc( sizeof *stack );
...
stack->array = malloc( stack->capacity * sizeof *stack->array );
```

Unless you're using a C++ compiler or a C compiler that predates the 1989 standard, the cast is unnecessary (and on C89 implementations, dangerous).

The `sizeof` expressions use the dereferenced target expression, rather than a type name; this cleans up a little of the visual clutter, and it reduces maintenance if you ever decide to change the type of the target variable (from `int *` to `double *`, for example).  The type of the expression `*stack` is `struct Stack`, so it follows that `sizeof *stack == sizeof (struct Stack)`.  Similarly, the type of the expression `*stack->array` is `int`, so `sizeof *stack->array == sizeof (int)`.  Note that parentheses are only required if the operand of `sizeof` is a type name.

---

<sup>1.  C99 introduced *variable-length arrays* whose size *can* be specified at runtime, but they won't work in this context for several reasons.</sup>

Comment: Thanx a lot for the detailed explanation..
Stack variable in main points to an instance of struct stack is it similar to saying that the stack variable is an object of the struct stack which has the copy of all the members of struct stack?
what additional advantage do we get by implementing this using structures rather than a simple stack using array?
Also in the last line u said if it changes from int to double so it's better to write in the second way but wouldn't it be simpler in the first way by just changing the (int) to (double)?